# How to - Sine-like function with slight displaced peak

Tags: algebra-precalculus

First of all, i am new here and i havent touched algebra in a while, like 2/3 years, so i am sorry if my question is confusing.

I want to model a sine function based on 3 parameters:

- amplitude
- phase
- angle between ]0,90[ where peak happens

I try to explain the shape in this
[drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiYze.png).

With amplitude and phase only (red function) its pretty basic, `Amp * sin(x - phase)`, but the peak happens always at 45 degress in ]0,90[ range (part in blue).

How can i change this function so that i can specify an angle between ]0,90[, for example 30, so that in a period of [0, 180], the peaks happen at 30 and 180-30 (green function)?

Or is there another function to get that kind of shape?

Comment: Your changed function is no longer a sine wave, hence further data is required to predict anything about it. The permissible operations on a function for it to remain of the same nature are: 1) stretching/compressing about x/y axes. 2) Rotating by any given angle. 3) shifting by any given length, in any direction. But your last operation, whereby you want the "base" of the wave to remain at x axis, but for peaks to occur at 45°, means that it is no longer a sine wave.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta ok, i understand, i will look into other functions then

Answer (score 1):

By definition through its power series or through triangles, a sinusoid is symmetric about the centre of any interval of length $\pi/2$.

So the function you want is not a sinusoid. I would suggest, based purely on your drawing, defining a sawtooth function with the peak at the desired place, calculating the Fourier coefficients of the first few harmonics, and adding them appropriately. Are you familiar with Fourier series?

But really more information is needed to know what properties you would like this function to have.

Comment: Sorry, i am not familiar with Fourier series.

Comment: Ah, okay. https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Fourier/Series/ExFS.html is a good first look, I think. Near the middle of the page, "Odd Sawtooth Wave" may be what you are looking for, if you take the average and the first harmonic.

Comment: thank you, i will look into this!